# ¿Por qué List<T>.Remove(T) solo remueve el primer elemento coincidente?

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Tengo un `List<string>` con información que puede variar dependiendo de las acciones tomadas y necesito remover todos los elementos que coincidan con el `string`.

He probado el siguiente código en el `List<T>`:

```
List<string> Strings = new List<string>() {
    "658", "123", "321", "123"
};
foreach (string s in Strings) Console.WriteLine(s); // Imprime: 658, 123, 321, 123
Strings.Remove("123");
foreach (string s in Strings) Console.WriteLine(s); // Imprime: 658, 321, 123
```

Y necesito que el útimo bucle `foreach` devuelva `658, 321`.

Se que puedo ejecutar un bucle que recorra el `List`, pero necesito entender por qué no se eliminan todos los elementos que coinciden.

Saludos.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hay varias alternativas para lo que buscas, podrias usar

```
List<string> Strings = new List<string>() {
    "658", "123", "321", "123"
};

foreach (string s in Strings) Console.WriteLine(s);
Strings.RemoveAll(x=> x=="123");
foreach (string s in Strings) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

o ayudarte con linq

```
List<string> Strings = new List<string>() {
    "658", "123", "321", "123"
};

foreach (string s in Strings) Console.WriteLine(s);
Strings = Strings.Where(x=> x != "123").ToList();
foreach (string s in Strings) Console.WriteLine(s);
```

con linq básicamente filtras quitando el valor que no quieres

Answer (score 7):

El `Remove` sólo elimina el primer elemento, para eliminar todas las coincidencias tienes varias opciones:

1. Utilizar el `RemoveAll` ([documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx)), en concreto:

   ```
   Strings.RemoveAll(x => x == "123");
   ```

   Importante destacar que el `RemoveAll` **actualiza** la lista actual.
2. Otra buena opción es utilizar Linq para hacerlo (con `Select`):

   ```
   List<string> Strings2 = Strings.Select(x => x != "123"); //Sin el ToList()!
   ```
3. También con Linq pero con `where` (prefiero la opción del `Select`):

   ```
   List<string> Strings2 = Strings.Where(x => x != "123").ToList();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

No soy un experto en C# pero tal vez deberías de usar el método [RemoveAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) en vez de Remove

```
Console.WriteLine("\n{0} elementos quitados mediante RemoveAll(MetodoDeFiltrado()).", 
            lista.RemoveAll(MetodoDeFiltrado()));
```